# Adding a private view when a user is logged in using Auth0 on react

Tags: reactjs, auth0

I'm having trouble on s showing the private view for the logged in users only.

would it be possible to show some partial links on my tool bar for public view and add something when a user is logged in?

**Links.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import LoopIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Loop';
import LocalLibraryIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LocalLibrary';
import LinkIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Link';
import {useAuth0} from '@auth0/auth0-react';

export const links = [
  {
    name: 'Public View',
    icon:  LocalLibraryIcon,
    route: '/',

  },
  {
    name: 'Public View',
    icon: LoopIcon,
    route: '/CICD',
  },
  {
    name: 'Public View',
    icon: LinkIcon,
    route: '/Project_Links'
  },

  //isAuthenticated show this
  {
    name: 'Private View',
    icon: LinkIcon,
    route: 'Project_Links',
  },
];
```

***Layout.js***

```
        <List>
          {links.map(({ icon: Icon, ...link }, index) => (
            <ListItem
              button
              key={link.name}
              onClick={() => gotoRoute(link.route)}
              selected={link.route === location.pathname}
            >
              <ListItemIcon>
                <Icon />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={link.name} />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
```

Comment: After multiple times trying I got  it. Thanks guys!